# Как исправить код, для нормального его выполнения?

Tags: javascript, cookie

Использую для тура по сайту плагин [jQuery jTour](https://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-tour-the-flexible-tour-plugin/1052564), тур предусматривает переход по нескольким страницам сайта, и состоит из трех этапов. Задача состоит записывать в cookie состояние тура на событие onFinish. К примеру первая часть тура заканчивается на определенной странице, вторая часть тура стартует только по окончанию первой части, и с того момента,где окончился первая часть. Для удобства каждый этап тура обозначается 1, 2, 3 для записи в cookie:

```js
//Для запуска первого тура я написал (он стартует с кнопки):

$(function() {
  var tourdata1 = [...........]; //условия положения элементов на странице

  var myTour = jTour(tourdata1, {
    axis: 'y',
    autostart: !getCookie('jTour'),
    onStop: function(current) {},
    onChange: function(current) {},
    onFinish: function() {
      setCookie('jTour', 1, {
        expires: 365,
        path: ''
      });
    },
    animationIn: 'slideDown',
    animationOut: 'hide',
    easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
    scrollDuration: 600
  });

  $('#starttour').click(function() {
    myTour.start();
  });

});

//тур отрабатывает свой участок и записывает в cookie значение: jTour 1

//второй этап тура я записал следующим образом:

$(function() {
  var turdata2 = [.........];

  var myTour2 = jTour(turdata2, {
    axis: 'y',
    autostart: !getCookie('jTour'),
    onStop: function(current) {},
    onChange: function(current) {},
    onFinish: function() {
      setCookie('jTour', 2, {
        expires: 365,
        path: ''
      });
    },
    animationIn: 'slideDown',
    animationOut: 'hide',
    easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
    scrollDuration: 600
  });

  function checkCookie() {
    var cookie = getCookie("jTour");
    if (cookie == 1) {
      myTour2.start();
    }
  }

});
```

но почему-то второй тур запускается первым... записывая в cookie jTour 2

Как правильно задать условие: что второй тур стартует только после окончание первого.

Буду благодарен за любой совет. 
Спасибо.

Comment: window.onload может это поможет загрузка будет сразу срабатывать или settieout

Comment: Использовал, но это не решило проблемы